# C# Looping through a list and extracting specific data

Tags: c#

I need to loop through a list of type TrackRecordVM and extract data from fields that are only assigned to fields names Jan, Feb, Mar,Apr, May, Jun, July,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec

This is the list that I am looping through

```
public class TrackRecordVM
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public decimal? Jan { get; set; }
    public decimal? Feb { get; set; }
    public decimal? Mar { get; set; }
    public decimal? Apr { get; set; }
    public decimal? May { get; set; }
    public decimal? Jun { get; set; }
    public decimal? Jul { get; set; }
    public decimal? Aug { get; set; }
    public decimal? Sep { get; set; }
    public decimal? Oct { get; set; }
    public decimal? Nov { get; set; }
    public decimal? Dec { get; set; }
    public decimal? YTD { get; set; }
    public decimal? Bmrk { get; set; }
    public string BmrkName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the loop. Whats the best way of doing it

```
 List<TrackRecordVM> trackRecordVm;

            foreach (var trackRecord in fundTrackRecord)
            {
                trackRecordVm = trackRecord.TrackRecord;

                foreach (var track in trackRecordVm)
                {


                }
            }
```

Comment: How about trying LINQ

Comment: `extract data from fields that are only assigned to fields names`  Consider clarifying

Comment: What i meant is fields Jan, Feb, Mar,Apr, May, Jun, July,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I am basically looping through a list that contains fields other than month names. I need to extract data only from month fields

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably have an easier time with Linq.

Something along the lines of this (just repeat this for whichever members you need):

`var jan = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Jan).ToList();`

`var dec = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.dec).ToList();`

`var newList = new List<decimal?>();
 newList.AddRange(jan);
 newList.AddRange(dec);`

Comment: I tried this and getting error cannot assign void to implicity types variable

Comment: trackRecordVm = trackRecord.TrackRecord;

                var jan = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Jan).ToList();
                var feb = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Feb).ToList();
                var mar = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Mar).ToList();
                var apr = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Apr).ToList();
                var may = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.May).ToList();
                var jun = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Jun).ToList();
                var dec = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Dec).ToList();
                var monthsData = jan.AddRange(dec);

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this, but you could do exactly what you ask for like this:

```
    public static void DoIt()
    {
        TrackRecordVM record = new TrackRecordVM();

        string[] months = new string[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };

        foreach (decimal? value in record.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties()
            .Where(p => months.Contains(p.Name))
            .Select(pi => pi.GetValue(record, null)))
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
```

Or, you could create an enumerable from within your record class, like this:

```
public class TrackRecordVM
{
    public decimal? Jan { get; set; }
    public decimal? Feb { get; set; }
    public decimal? Not { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<decimal?> GetMonths()
    {
        yield return Jan;
        yield return Feb;
    }
}
```

I prefer the second option, myself.