# Error cannot convert IEnumerable<double?> to IEnumerable<double>

Tags: c#

Following up from my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55575273/c-sharp-looping-through-a-list-and-extracting-specific-data), I have list of the type `List<double?>` and need to pass it to method that accepts only `List<Double>`. I am currently getting an error cannot convert `IEnumerable<double?>` to `IEnumerable<double>`. If you notice the method `AverageGain` below accepts only `IEnumerable<double>`.

How do i get around this error ?

```
 Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<double>> returnsList = new Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<double>>();
(double Monthly, double Annual) averageGain;

 trackRecordVm = trackRecord.TrackRecord;
            fundId = trackRecord.FundId;

            var jan = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Jan).ToList();
            var feb = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Feb).ToList();
            var mar = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Mar).ToList();
            var apr = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Apr).ToList();
            var may = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.May).ToList();
            var jun = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Jun).ToList();
            var jul = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Jul).ToList();
            var aug = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Aug).ToList();
            var sep = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Sep).ToList();
            var oct = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Oct).ToList();
            var nov = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Nov).ToList();
            var dec = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Dec).ToList();

var monthData = new List<double?>();
            monthData.AddRange(jan);
            monthData.AddRange(feb);
            monthData.AddRange(mar);
            monthData.AddRange(apr);
            monthData.AddRange(may);
            monthData.AddRange(jun);
            monthData.AddRange(jul);
            monthData.AddRange(aug);
            monthData.AddRange(sep);
            monthData.AddRange(oct);
            monthData.AddRange(nov);
            monthData.AddRange(dec);

            returnsList.Add(fundId, monthData);



    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<double?>> entry in returnsList)
        {
            list1 = new List<Tuple<string, double, double>>();


            averageGain = riskMatrix.AverageGain(entry.Value);

            list1.Add(new Tuple<string, double, double>("AverageGain", averageGain.Monthly, entry.Annual));

            list.Add(entry.Key, list1);

        }


    public (double Monthly, double Annual) AverageGain(IEnumerable<double> ReturnsList)
    {

        double returnList = ReturnsList.GainMean();
        return (Monthly: returnList, Annual: returnList * Math.Pow(12, 0.5));
    }
```

Comment: Storing the months in dedicated properties makes their handling tedious. If you had a single property `public double[] Months { get; } = new double[12];` You could get the month data like this: `IEnumerable<double> monthData = trackRecordVm.SelectMany(x => x.Months);` with a single statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `returnList.Select(v => v.Value)` to access the values of a nullable value.

This uses System.Linq.

In your specific example, you'd end up with this:

```
averageGain = riskMatrix.AverageGain(entry.Value.Select(v => v.Value));
```

It may also be important, in case of nulls in your IEnumerable, to protect against such things, like this:

```
averageGain = riskMatrix.AverageGain(entry.HasValue ? entry.Value : 0D);
```

If there's the possibility of having a null `entry`, then you'd need even more checks, but I'm pretty sure that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: how does this behave with null values ​​within IEnumerable?

Comment: `.GetValueOrDefault()` would be a better option, or even better would be `returnList.Where(p => p.HasValue).Select(p => p.Value);`

Comment: is it in the forloop

Comment: @GianfrancescoAurecchia I've made the assumption that there would be no nulls.  I'll make that clear in my response.  If you were to expect nulls then you would need to provide a default, of which I'm not sure of the OPs requirement.

Answer (score 1):

`double?` can be `null`, so there is no explicit conversion between that type and `double` (what do you do with null values?), but one nice thing about the `Nullable<T>` struct is that is has a couple of helpful methods/properties: `HasValue` and `GetValueOrDefault`.

`HasValue` returns `true` if the object has been assigned a value (other than null), and `GetValueOrDefault` returns the `double` value if it's been assigned, otherwise it returns the default value for the type (which is `0` in the case of a `double`).

So, you can either return all the values which have been assigned, or get all values with default values (`0`) for `null` items:

```
List<double?> nullables = new List<double?> {1, null, 2, null, 3};

// This will contain {1, 2, 3}
List<double> values = nullables
    .Where(item => item.HasValue)
    .Select(item => item.Value)
    .ToList();

// This will contain {1, 0, 2, 0, 3}
List<double> valuesAndDefaults = nullables
    .Select(item => item.GetValueOrDefault())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

As above, but there are two ways of doing this:

```
returnList.Where(f => f.HasValue).Select(f => f.Value);
```

Gives you all the months that have data and

```
returnList.Select(f => f.GetValueOrDefault());
```

returns 0 where there isn't a value for a month.

Comment: returnsList is dictionary of id and IEnumerable<double>.  its not recognising the word HasValue

Comment: Any type? has a value or is null. double? can be queried with .HasValue, which tells you if it is not null.

Comment: When i do f. , i mean f and DOT, I get options key and value

Comment: Reading the question further, you have a List<KeyValuePair<>>, you need to extract your IEnumerable<double?> out of that first.

Comment: Yes thats what  i menioned above that its a dictionary

Comment: Its not recognising HasValue for dictionary

Comment: I just need to be more concerned witt conversion of monthsData as I am adding that to the dictionaty

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by  var finalMonthList = monthData.Where(f => f.HasValue).Select(f => f.Value);  returnsList.Add(fundId, finalMonthList);